# Post-EOL security patches for PHP7

Tags: php, vulnerability

Imagine the following situation: you have a third party software which still uses PHP7 despite of the EOL.

The risk there will be further post-EOL vulnerabilities is as I estimated considerably higher that zero.

If it's not possible to migrate away from that third party software immediately, is there any chance the community will publish post-EOL patches? (even if you will have to compile the engine yourself)

Sorry, to be more precise: are there well-known release groups, at least one, offering such post EOL patches for PHP7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for "release groups" (no idea what that means) - you could get LTS patches from the original vendor:

https://www.zend.com/services/php-long-term-support#get-long-term-support-for-your-php-project

I presume this costs money.